# HSQLDB Temporary Cached Table

Tags: hsqldb

To use cached tables, can I use the driver URL: `jdbc:hsqldb:mem` or should I use `jdbc:hsqldb:file`?
I need a non-persistent temporary table that will hold more data that can fit in memory.

It's unclear from the documentation if using `create cached table` syntax with the JDBC URL of `jdbc:hsqldb:mem` actually uses a cached table, or does it use memory always since the URL is memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use `jdbc:hsqldb:file:<file path>`. You can turn logging off with SET FILES LOG FALSE, in order to speed up operations when you store only temporary data.

Because the jdbc:hsqldb:mem: URL creates an all-in-memory table, `CREATE CACHED TABLE` is interpreted as `CREATE MEMORY TABLE`